# Python list in list undo

Tags: python, list, undo

I'm making a program that will do some operations like add, insert, pop on a list of numbers.
I have to also make an "undo" function and for that I thought about making a list in list to save up my list every step of the way but my tests are not working. Here's the code:

```
def backup(l):
        lbackup.append(list(l))
```

<-- here I save the list every step of the way by calling this function

```
> def undo(l):
>     l=lbackup[len(lbackup)-1] # here I give my list the previous list
>     del lbackup[len(lbackup)-1]  # here I delete the sublist from the history
```

My test:

```
def testUndo():
    add(lista, 1)
    backup(lista)
    add(lista, 2)
    backup(lista)
    add(lista,111111)
    print(lbackup)
    print(lista)
    undo(lista)
    print(lista)
    print(lbackup)
```

So I checked the inside of the Undo function and it's working! It actually changed the value of my list to what I wanted but once it left the function and got to the print after undo in the test... it had the same values again. I know lists are mutable and that might be a problem but is there anything I could do? Sorry if I wasnt clean enough.

Answer (score 0):

When you call, say, `undo(lista)`, the `l` inside of `undo` may be the same list as `lista`, but assigning to `l` does not change `lista`.  If instead you had `undo` return `l`, and assign the value returned by `undo` back to `list`, that would make the change you seem to want.